# understanding the conditional probability of random variables for gaussian cases

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am new to conditional probability and was wondering if anyone could help me out understanding this probability better.

$$P(aX+bZ\geq t \mid X)$$
Here, X and Z are i.i.d N(0,1)

To be more specific, I tried to calculate $Var(P(aX+bZ\geq t \mid X))$ with respect to X, but I can't make a move without truly understanding what the inner really means. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- By the  Doob-Dynkin lemma $\mathbb P\{aX+bZ\ge t\,|\,\,X\}$, or more generally,
  any conditional expectation w.r.t. $X$, in particular,
  $$\tag{1}
  \mathbb E[f(X,Z)\,|\,X]
  $$
  is a deterministic function of the random variable $X\,.$ Here $f$ is a deterministic function of $X$ and $Z$. Let's write this as
  $$
  \mathbb E[f(X,Z)\,|\,X]=g(X)\,.
  $$
- When  $X$ and $Z$ are independent then $g$ is simply
  $$
  g(x)=\mathbb E[f(x,Z)]\,\quad x\in\mathbb R\,.
  $$
  In other words, the conditional expectation (1) is essentially an unconditional expectation that depends on a real parameter $x\,.$ We get (1) by "plugging" $X$ in for $x$ after taking that unconditional expectation.
- When we apply all this to your $\mathbb P\{aX+bZ\ge t\,|\,\,X\}$ it turns out that we only have to calculate the probability (for arbitrary $x\in\mathbb R$)
  $$\tag{2}
  \mathbb P\{ax+bZ\ge t\}
  $$
  which is the complement of the CDF of the normal distribution
  with mean $ax$ and standard deviation $b^2\,.$

Comment: @GerryG Was this answer helpful ?